# How many users does Presto DB support?

Tags: sql, database, presto

We are looking into Presto DB documents and blogs to understand its usage for one of the projects. One of the questions that we have is

"How many users can concurrently fire queries in a presto DB?"

Is there a fixed number of users or we can have as many users login?

Is there a limit on number of concurrent queries which can be fired? (other than max concurrent queries can be set for user in queue config)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no hard limits. It just depends on your workload and cluster size. Presto can easily support 50-100 concurrent queries